# AWK: How to delete last pattern?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a path:

```
/home/alejo/Desktop/Proyecto_UIS-MINCIENCIAS/qmmm_propranolol_aescorcia/A_PSF-NUEVO/ORIII/MCC/out/mcc_oriii_after_centering.pdb
```

I want to have:

```
/home/alejo/Desktop/Proyecto_UIS-MINCIENCIAS/qmmm_propranolol_aescorcia/A_PSF-NUEVO/ORIII/MCC/out/
```

What I have tried:

```
a="/home/alejo/Desktop/Proyecto_UIS-MINCIENCIAS/qmmm_propranolol_aescorcia/A_PSF-NUEVO/ORIII/MCC/out/mcc_oriii_after_centering.pdb"
echo $a | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'
```

But, what I get is:

```
mcc_oriii_after_centering.pdb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the value `$NF` to the empty string:

```
$ echo "$a" | awk -F'/' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {$NF=""; print}'
/home/alejo/Desktop/Proyecto_UIS-MINCIENCIAS/qmmm_propranolol_aescorcia/A_PSF-NUEVO/ORIII/MCC/out/
```

`BEGIN{OFS=FS}` sets the output field separator to be the same as the input field separator before the start of processing - otherwise the output will be separated by the default spaces instead of slashes.

At least in GNU awk, you could instead delete the last field altogether by decrementing `NF` (although this will give an output without the trailing slash):

```
awk -F'/' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {NF--; print}'
```

You could also use shell parameter expansion to avoid awk altogether:

```
$ echo "${a%/*}/"
/home/alejo/Desktop/Proyecto_UIS-MINCIENCIAS/qmmm_propranolol_aescorcia/A_PSF-NUEVO/ORIII/MCC/out/
```

`${parameter%pattern}` returns the value of shell variable `parameter` with the shortest trailing match of `pattern` removed - see for example [BashGuide: Parameter Expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

Or simply use the `dirname` command.

Comment: would you expand what means: 1. `BEGIN{OFS=FS}` and 2. `${a%/*}/` in order to learn, thank you in advance

Comment: @Another.Chemist please see edited answer